# Kuberentes cluster IP vs FQDN of a service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm curious what's the benefit of using Cluster IP in kubernetes. 
I know if one app needs to access service of other app. It can directly use FQDN of that service, without the trouble of creating Cluster IP.
But i still see lots of places Cluster IP being used.

Answer (score 0):

From my exp FQDN  uses much more, however there are pretty much examples with Cluster IP direct usage. Benefit? dont think so. I think this is more philosophical question and you can do the way you prefer more.

Referring to  [Connect a Front End to a Back End Using a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/) from kubernetes page will show optimal way how to do similar things